# How to add another string with another string in an existing string table field

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Im trying to add a SenderID ($senderID) to another SenderID string that is already existing in my phpAdmin table. So if i had the string "monkeys" and I wanted to insert a new string "bananas" how do I update that field to say "monkeysbananas"?

This is the code I'm currently trying to use to try to combine these strings in the database:

```
$sql = "UPDATE database.table SET SenderID = SenderID.'$senderID' WHERE id = '1';
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the  [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function in MySQL for string concatenation:

```
$sql = "UPDATE database.table SET SenderID  = CONCAT(SenderID, '$senderID') WHERE id = 1;";
```